# create a deep copy of Buffer array in java

Tags: java, buffer, nio

How can i create a deep copy of a Buffer array without any change in original
  in  java. I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366925/deep-copy-duplicate-of-javas-bytebuffer) but it cant solve my problem.

i am getting a Buffer[] array and want to create a copy like this using above link but Buffer class does not provide put method.

```
private Buffer [] clone(Buffer [] original) {
    Buffer clone[] = new Buffer [2];
    clone[0] = Buffer.allocate(original[0].capacity());
    original[0].rewind();// copy from the beginning
    clone[0].put(original[0]);
    original[0].rewind();
    clone[0].flip();

    clone[1] = Buffer.allocate(original[1].capacity());
    original[1].rewind();// copy from the beginning
    clone[1].put(original[1]);
    original[1].rewind();
    clone[1].flip();

    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Why can't it solve your problem?

Comment: It doesn't provide an allocate() method either. How come you have a Buffer[] without knowing what types they are?

Comment: @EJP actually i am using a third party library javacv which provides me audio samples as a Buffer array.