# Duplicate the audio ByteBuffer in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, audio, bytebuffer, exoplayer

I'm trying to process the audio buffer in the [Android ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/). In the *writeBuffer* function of the *DefaultAudioSink* class, Audio data's coming in a ByteBuffer object. In my case, I want to get the values (as Byte[] if possible) from this ByteBuffer to process the datas before to create a new ByteBuffer and give it to the audioTrack.

I firstly tried to clone the original ByteBuffer in a new ByteBuffer, then send it to the audioTrack (as described in [Deep copy duplicate() of Java's ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366925/deep-copy-duplicate-of-javas-bytebuffer) ), to verify it is still working. But the result is an empty buffer for the destination AND the original one (as with this solution)

```
public static ByteBuffer clone(ByteBuffer original) {
    ByteBuffer clone = ByteBuffer.allocate(original.capacity());
    original.rewind();//copy from the beginning
    clone.put(original);
    original.rewind();
    clone.flip();
    return clone;
}
```

or something like accelerated audio (if I remove the rewind calls).

A simple

```
ByteBuffer newBuffer = buffer.duplicate();
```

has the same behavior.

I'm trying to understand why I can't get a working *duplicated* audio ByteBuffer, that I can transfer to the AudioTrack and hear the same sound.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying and wrapping the returned ByteBuffer's array?  i.e.

```
byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(original.array(), original.array().length)
return ByteBuffer.wrap(copy, 0, copy.length)
```

Comment: I tried... The ByteBuffer that came back is full of zero -_-

Comment: Interesting.  Have you checked to see what the length is before the copying operation?